# Differences with CFscript calling value methods

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm working with ColdFusion and CFScript. At the moment I've no problems, but noticed that I can call values in 3 ways:

1. `Value`
2. `'Value'`
3. `'#Value#'`

What are the differences between them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. `Value`

CF searches for a variable called `Value` (case insensitive) starting with the `VARIABLES` scope and then progressing through other scopes (like `URL` and `FORM`), stopping at the first variable found.

> 2. `'Value'`

A literal string with the characters `V`, `a`, `l`, `u` and `e`.

> 3. `'#Value#'`

A string where `Value` will be evaluated (CF evalautes stuff between `#`). If the variable `Value` (case insensitive) is a so called `simple value`, the variable will be cast to a string. Otherwise, an exception is thrown since non-simple (ie complex ) values are not automatically cast as strings. This is basically equivalent to `'' & Value & ''` (string concatenation).

---

```
Value = 'Hello World !!';

writeOutput(Value);
>> Hello World !!

writeOutput('Value');
>> Value

writeOutput('#Value#');
>> Hello World !!

writeOutput( evaluate('Value') );
>> Hello World !!
```

Comment: In addition, unlike syntax #1, variables that are enclosed in quotes *must* also be enclosed in pound signs. Otherwise the CF engine will not recognize the variable as something to be evaluated. While syntatically valid, it is usually not necessary to enclose CF variables in quotes. Also, keep in mind the `evaluate()` example above is just for demonstration. Since most scopes are structures, you would typically use associative array notation instead, ie `scopeName["variableName"]`. Plus, `evaluate()` is very permissive and can pose security risks in some cases.